# Where is the default logging file in Scala's SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

The [SBT document](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/logging.html) says that "When a command is run, more detailed logging output is sent to a file than to the screen (by default). ..."

Where is the logging file?

If I use a logging function in my program, where can I find those logs after the program is finished?

Comment: What "logging function" are you using? :)

Comment: I want to use the debug method in the ScalaLogging, https://github.com/typesafehub/scalalogging, to collect a batch of outputs from a running program.

Comment: (for anyone who googles this question looking for where the output of SBT tasks is logged to...) Check out `./target/streams/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are simply trying to log to a file using an SLF4J compatible logger (as suggested by the link in your comment) I'd propose you use Logback for logging, as explained [here](http://blog.knoldus.com/2012/03/23/quickknol-integrating-logback-with-scala/).

It is fairly simple to configure (for simple use cases), including where log outputs are sent to. The linked to tutorial only configures a console appender, that is, the logged output will be sent to the console. You can configure a [`FileAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender) (i.e. sending log outputs to a file) like this (in your `logback.xml`):

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
   <file>testFile.log</file>
   <append>true</append>
   <encoder>
     <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
   </encoder>
 </appender>
```

And then changing `<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />` from the tutorial to `<appender-ref ref="FILE" />`. You should really take a look at the logback / SLF4J docs in order to figure out how to set up more complex logging configurations if you need it, but this should get you started.

After setting everything up (i.e. adding logback as a dependency in `build.sbt` and creating your `logback.xml` configuration in `src/main/resources`), you can then invoke the logger like so:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import ch.qos.logback.core.util.StatusPrinter
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

object LogTester extends App{
  def logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("KDURLFilter")
  StatusPrinter.print((LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory).asInstanceOf[LoggerContext])
  logger.info("vikas")
}
```

---

## Example

I've created [an example SBT project](https://github.com/x3ro/scala-sbt-logback-example) in which you can see a running logback configuration.

Comment: There is another called Loglady, https://github.com/dln/loglady, it can back at Logback.

Comment: Efficiency is a concern, lots of IO dumping to a file during a long program running, wouldn't it make the program run slower. But it seems the way as logging be.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to redirect a sbt console's output to a file. I can run "last run" in sbt console to get debug info during a programming run, but I want to write it into a file for record. That's why I was looking for logging function. :) Thank you for your example on github! I appreciate it.

Comment: I got it. Logback's configuration file can customize those.